# Create an expandable list with react native

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs, react-native, expandable

I am presenting a list of items with this code

```
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
          Categories
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.navSubSectionStyle}>

        {data.categories.map(category =>
          <Text key={category.id} >
            { (JSON.parse(category.name)) }
          </Text>
          )}
        </View>
```

I want to be able to expand/collapse the list, with animation, when I click on the "Category" text. Is there any react native element for that?

Answer (score 2):

Set initial state of collapse to false.

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        collapse: !this.state.collapse
    })
}
<View>
    <TouchableHighlight onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <Text style={styles.sectionHeadingStyle}>
           Categories
        </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
    {
        this.state.collapse ? 
        <View style={styles.navSubSectionStyle}>

            {data.categories.map(category =>
            <Text key={category.id} >
                { (JSON.parse(category.name)) }
            </Text>
            )}
        </View>
        : null

    }
</View>
```

Comment: The `</View>`s here are a bit confusing.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a npm package like [react-native-collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible)